# Kafka error invalid recieve size with minus value

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

I'm running kafka kraft with three nodes, but the kafka show logs receive invalid size

> org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = -720899)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:92)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
> at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:1055)
> at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:959)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

how to fix it, is it relate with kafka max message bytes ?
is is the problem on the producer or consumer ?

Comment: Needs more details about how you've configured the cluster and when you get this exception. For instance, I've seen similar error when using the wrong port/protocol for clients. Why did you tag this as python?